# Modify Specific Column in CSV via Python

Tags: python, csv, splunk

I'm trying to modify a specific column in a csv file in Splunk. The below code isn't working, and is generating the following.

```
External search command 'queryinc' returned error code 1. Script output = "Incident_Number,Incident_Status INC000000003050,Assigned INC000000003051,Assigned INC000000003052,Assigned INC000000003053,Assigned INC000000003054,Assigned INC000000003101,Assigned INC000000003102,Closed INC000000003103,Assigned INC000000003104,Closed "
```

Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong? I'm new to python, so I wouldn't be surprised if this was basic. `si.splunkHome()` just pulls the "Splunk Home" directory, which is defined within Splunk.

```
f = open(os.path.join(si.splunkHome(),"etc","apps","integration","lookups","incidents.csv"), 'a+')
for line in f:
    columns = line.split(',')
    columns[7] = '%s' % (statusResult)
    f.write( ','.join(bits))
    f.close()
```

Comment: How did you get that error message "External search command..."? I would expect a bit different message, if you run the code, you have presented.

Comment: This is what Splunk throws when I run the custom command I've written in Splunk. It works fine without this code to modify the csv.

Comment: Is what you have provided complete content of the script? Or you have some `sys.exit(1)` there? It would explain, why is Splunk complaining.

Comment: `join(bits)` - where the `bits come form? They are constant or undefined.

Comment: If I could provide the full code of the script, I would, but NDAs and such. I can only provide an anonymized version of what I'm working on. This is appended to the end of a working script.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read and write to the same file at once. This is the problem.

You shall read the file first, thus using `open(fname, "r")`, and create new content somewhere beside, thus having `f2 = open(outfname, "a")` (or with "w" mode).

At the end, you shall delete the original csv file and move there the new one.

Reading and writing the same file is difficult and generally works if you have strict binary structure.

```
import os
fname = os.path.join(si.splunkHome(),"etc","apps","integration","lookups","incidents.csv")
with open(fname, "r") as fr, open("tmpfile.csv", "w") as fw:
    for line in fr:
        columns = line.split(',')
        columns[7] = '%s' % (statusResult)
        fw.write( ','.join(bits))
```

Note, that this code does not run, as it contains some external stuff I do not know about.

Comment: This is throwing the same error from before, but it's a good start, as I think I see where you're going with it. Thanks!